# jQuery refuses to post after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I've added some validation to my jQuery code to check for blank text fields before it posts a message but it doesn't seem to be working. No messages are being posted at all to my wall. Any idea how I can fix this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="container"> <span id="text_header">Virtual Idea Wall</span> </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="chat"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
      <p>
        <label for="title">Please give your idea a title</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="message">Please provide details of your idea</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" id="sendmessage">
      </p>
      </input>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var $messageForm = $('#sendmessage');
    var $messageTitle = $('#title');
    var $messageBox = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');

    $messageForm.click(function () {
        if ($.trim($("#title").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        }
        if ($.trim($("#message").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', '<b>' + $messageTitle.val() + '</b>' + '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' + $messageBox.val());
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
        }

        socket.on('new message', function (data) {
            $chat.prepend(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click function is not passing in the event "e" so that would stop this from working when you make a call to "e.preventDefault()".

I made this jsfiddle - no socket support - but it does alert my message.
http://jsfiddle.net/4v2QT/

This is the only change (the e passing into the function)

```
$messageForm.click(function (e) {
    ... code goes here!
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to make any difference. If the event object isn't referred to, the unused argument is unnecessary.

Comment: There is a call to "e.preventDefault();" though.... that is why I pointed that out. Since I'm not using sockets in my example I might not be seeing the true issue.

Comment: Hah, well that's a different matter. The code will halt right there because `e` is undefined - Would be a better answer to point that out (please edit the answer). Since the event is stopped in all permutations it should really be the ~first line. +1.

Comment: Updated the answer and made it more clear why the variable needs to be passed in.