# jquery click does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone have an idea why my jQuery click won't work?

It's attached to a hyperlink.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(".delete").click(function(e) {
        alert("Hello");
    });

    var socket = io.connect();
    var $messageForm = $('#sendmessage');
    var $messageTitle = $('#title');
    var $messageBox = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');

    $messageForm.click(function (e) {
        if ($.trim($("#title").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        }
        if ($.trim($("#message").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', 
               '<b>' + $messageTitle.val() + '</b>' + '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'  
               + $messageBox.val() + '&nbsp;' + '[' +  
               '<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>' + ']');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
        }
    });

    socket.on('new message', function (data) {
        $chat.prepend(data + "<br/>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Which click is not working?

Comment: Wasn't it just [working a minute ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821368/jquery-keeps-posting-an-extra-message-each-time-i-click-submit) and causing you problems? Or is it the new $(".delete').click line?  It would be helpful if you could provide your html as well.

Comment: Are you sure the JavaScript is initialized AFTER the HTML? Otherwise the elements won't be loaded.

Comment: Why are you creating three questions for the same thing!?
 - This one
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820772/jquery-refuses-to-post-after-validation
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821368/jquery-keeps-posting-an-extra-message-each-time-i-click-submit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the delete links are dynamically generated, you need to use event delegation:

```
$('#chat').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to modify your jquery initialization like this:

```
(function($){ }(jQuery)
```

If your script still doesn't fire the click event, check if $messageForm exists, using console.log($messageForm). You can modify var $messageForm in var messageForm from what I seen that variable does not need a scope so wide. I hope this could help you